# How can I find the minimum required radius to draw a visible circle?

Tags: unity, c#

The problem is that if for example xradius and yradius are set to 5 and the object is too big the circle will be hide under the object and won't be visible.
So I want to find the minimum radius require to draw a visible circle.

So I'm trying to use a recurse and loop over all the childs including the root objects to find what is the biggest radius and then to draw a circle according to the biggest radius.

I created a new method FindRadius.
The problem is how to get from this method the biggest radius from the List and then how to draw the circle on this radius size ? What xradius and yardius will be after finding the biggest radius ?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))]
public class DrawCircle : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(0, 50)]
    public int segments = 50;
    [Range(0, 50)]
    public float xradius = 5;
    [Range(0, 50)]
    public float yradius = 5;
    public bool minimumRequireRadius = false;
    LineRenderer line;
    private List<float> radiusList = new List<float>();

    void Start()
    {
        FindRadius(transform);

        line = gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        line.positionCount = segments + 1;
        line.useWorldSpace = false;
        CreatePoints();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        CreatePoints();
    }

    void CreatePoints()
    {
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;

        float angle = 20f;

        for (int i = 0; i < (segments + 1); i++)
        {
            x = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * xradius;
            z = Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * yradius;

            line.SetPosition(i, new Vector3(x, 0, z));

            angle += (360f / segments + 1);
        }
    }

    private float FindRadius(Transform root)
    {
        foreach (Transform child in root)
        {
            TraverseHierarchy(child);

            var rend = child.GetComponent<Renderer>();
            if (rend != null)
            {
                float radius = rend.bounds.extents.magnitude;
                radiusList.Add(radius);
            }
        }

        return radiusList[0];
    }
}
```

This is for RTS games too when selecting a unit and there should be a circle around it mark that the unit have been selected.

For example now there is a circle drawn on the MissilesTurret the problem is that the circle radius is xradius 5 and yradius 5 the circle is too short and hiding under the turret base part so it can't be seen only if I will make a lot of zoom in:

[image: Base part]

And this is after making zoom in to the base part:

[image: Circle under base]

Now if before running the game I'm changing the radius of the circle from 5/5 to for example xradius and yradius to 10 now you can see the circle:

[image: Circle]

My problem is how do I know what radius the circle should be drawn for each unit/s ? Each unit have another radius/size. I don't want to draw it with the mouse for selecting yet I want it to be drawn and selected automatic. So I thought to calculate the minimum required radius for drawing the circle to be see it.

Comment: Can you show us an example of your object setup, and draw a circle on it, representing your desired output?

Comment: @DMGregory Edited my question with screenshots and more explains. I wonder how do I know what radius should I set before running the game so it will draw big enough circle to see it. radius of 5 is too small circle. But radius of 7.3 might be big enough to see the circle and not too big.

Comment: So the feature you're trying to implement is something like a selection ring drawn on the ground around a selected unit? Please remember to explain this context at the start of a new question - assume you're talking to someone who's never seen your game before, because you probably are. ;)

Comment: @DMGregory Right this is the effect I'm trying to make. And you tright I will add this to my question :)